# Converting Integer to time in R

Tags: r

I have the integers 0 to 23 and want to convert them to time format (POSIXct). So that 0 becomes 00:00, 1 becomes 01:00 and 23 becomes 23:00. How do I do that?

Comment: Using `sprintf` to correctly format the time, we can `as.POSIXct(sprintf("%02d:00:00",0:24),format = "%H",origin = "1970-01-01")`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `as.ITime` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
as.ITime(sprintf('%02d:00', 0:23))
```